# get all posts from all categories with pagination

Tags: php, wordpress

i have 50 categories and every category have 100 post. i have a page template, on this page i want to show category with 5-5 posts but in pagination. 
I have used this below code but no any pagination and no any post found only category names coming.

```
$args = array(
'type'                     => 'post',
'child_of'                 => 0,
'parent'                   => '',
'orderby'                  => 'ID',
'order'                    => 'ASC',
'hide_empty'               => 1,
'hierarchical'             => 1,
'exclude'                  => '',
'include'                  => '',
'number'                   => '',
'taxonomy'                 => 'category',
'pad_counts'               => false 
);

$categories = get_categories($args);
foreach($categories as $category){ $catId[] = $category->term_id; }
$catId_comma_separated = implode(",", $catId);      

$myposts = get_posts(array('numberposts' => 5, 'offset' => 0, 'cat' => $catId_comma_separated, 'post_status'=>'publish', 'order'=>'ASC' ));
query_posts( "cat = $catId_comma_separated");
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
echo '<li>';
    the_title();
    echo '</li>';
endwhile;
// Reset Query
wp_reset_query();
custom_pagination();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **[paginate_link](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/paginate_links)** And do refer this answer from **[this question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/77661/next-posts-link-works-only-with-original-wp-query/77666#77666)**

```
<?php
$catPost = get_posts('cat=3&posts_per_page=-1'); //change this
   foreach ($catPost as $post) : setup_postdata($post); ?>

<h1><a>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>
    <?php the_excerpt(); ?> 

<p class="postinfo">Written by: <?php the_author_posts_link(); ?>
Posted on: <?php the_time('F j, Y'); ?> at <?php the_time('g:i a'); ?>
Categories: <?php the_category(', '); ?></p>
<hr />
<?php  endforeach;?>
```

OR Try This

```
<?php
// The Query
query_posts( array ( 'category_name' => 'your_category_name', 'posts_per_page' => -1 ) );

    // The Loop
    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
        echo '<h1>';
        the_title();
        echo '</h1>';
        the_excerpt();
        echo ' <p class="postinfo">Written by: ';
        the_author_posts_link();
        echo 'Posted on '
        the_date();
        echo 'Categories: '
        the_category(', ');
        echo '</p>';
        endwhile; ?>

          <?php

          // Reset Query
          wp_reset_query();

          ?>
```

Comment: thank you. my my custom pagination is working fine with other code. but not working with this code. leave the pagination topic. and please  tell me how to show all posts with category names only thanks..

Comment: you want to show all posts of all categories or any specific category??

Comment: yes i want to show all posts of all categories. leave the concept of pagination.  
but one page with only one category and all its posts.